# Forall exists formula

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory

This is a reference request.
Let $A$ be a formula in the language of rings which is of the form $\forall_{x_1}\dots\forall_{x_n}\exists_{y_1}\dots\exists_{y_m} F$, where $F$ is quantifier-free. I once read that if $A$ is valid for all finite fields, then it is valid for $\mathbb C$. Where would I find a proof of this statement?

Comment: Marker's book has this.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know a reference but it's not that hard to prove.

Let's call your formula $\varphi$. Then by classical arguments, the models of $\varphi$ are closed under directed union, in particular since $\varphi$ holds in any finite field, it holds in any $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p} = \displaystyle\bigcup_{n<\omega}\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, the algebraic closure of the field with $p$ elements, which is the directed union of its finite subfields.

But then by Los's theorem, $\varphi$ holds in $\displaystyle\prod_{p\in \mathbb{P}}\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/\mathcal{U}$ for any $\mathcal{U}$ ultrafilter on $\mathbb{P}$. Picking a non-principal ultrafilter yields a field isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, so the formula holds in $\mathbb{C}$ too.

Comment: I don't see why the resulting field would be isomorphic to the complex field (in absence of CH). But it will be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, which is what is important here.

Comment: @tomasz There is only one algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ and cardinality $2^\omega$.

Comment: @tomasz your argument is perhaps simpler, but the proof that the theory algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero is complete goes through (at least the proof I know) its $\kappa$-categoricity, for $\kappa$ uncountable, and since this field and $\mathbb{C}$ have the same cardinal...

Comment: The fact that the ultraproduct has size $2^{\aleph_0}$ is not completely trivial. The trick is finding a continuum family of sequences $(x_p)_{p\in \mathbb{P}}$ which you know to be distinct in the ultraproduct, i.e. such that $\{p\in \mathbb{P}\mid x_p = y_p\}$ is finite whenever $(x_p)$ and $(y_p)$ are distinct sequences in the family.

Comment: @AlexKruckman : Indeed, but it's a standard fact (unless I'm mistaken) that a nontrivial ultraproduct of countable structures has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$

Comment: @Max Yes indeed.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I know. I just didn't see that the ultraproduct has the right cardinality

Comment: @Max: completeness is also an easy consequence of quantifier elimination. I think this is older than the concept of categoricity (but probably not older than the observation that algebraic closure of a field is unique up to isomorphism, which implies categoricity). In any event, you need to show that ultraproduct has cardinality of the continuum, which is not trivial, as Alex said.

Comment: @tomasz : I know it needs to be proved but I didn't feel it was necessary to write it down since it is a classical result. If you wish I can add a proof of this fact ? (And indeed, I had forgotten about quantifier elimination for a minute)

Comment: @tomasz As a warmup, consider the ultraproduct (over $\mathbb{N}$, with respect to nonprincipal $\mathcal{U}$) of the family of sets $X_i$ defined recursively as $X_1=\{1, 2\}$, $X_{i+1}=\{1, ..., 2\cdot (\vert \prod_{j\le i}X_j \vert)\}$; there is a natural map $\pi$ from $2^\omega$ to $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}X_i$ such that $\rho(f)$ and $\rho(g)$ disagree cofinitely often whenever $f\not=g$. Since $\mathcal{U}$ is nonprinciple, this gives an injection of $2^\omega$ into $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}} X_i/\mathcal{U}$, hence the ultraproduct has cardinality at least continuum.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I've found the proof. It's just that I've never considered that before, and it was the first time I've heard of it, so I had just assumed that it's just independent of ZFC.